# Is it advisable to write a test case for every class in your program?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Im am just getting introduced to unit testing and test driven development. Thus far, I have only used Junit as testing framework. A question which emerged and for which I have not yet found a definite answer is: how much test cases do I need to write? Do I have to write a test case for every single class in my program? Or is this a stupid question because unit testing implies testing at the lowest (i.e. class) level?

I think writing a test case for every class is probably the more safe way to go (after all the more you test the lower the number of unforeseen bugs). But I was wondering if there are any widely agreed upon strategies regarding the amount of test cases to write?

Comment: Also see [How often should we write unit tests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538008/how-often-should-we-write-unit-tests)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no strict rules in this area, only guidelines. You usually have one test case per class, but there are different strategies:

- [TestCase Per Class](http://xunitpatterns.com/Testcase%20Class%20per%20Class.html)
- [TestCase Per Feature](http://xunitpatterns.com/Testcase%20Class%20per%20Feature.html)
- [TestCase Per Method](http://xunitpatterns.com/Testcase%20Class%20per%20Feature.html#Testcase%20Class%20Per%20Method)
- [TestCase Per User Story](http://xunitpatterns.com/Testcase%20Class%20per%20Feature.html#Testcase%20Class%20Per%20User%20Story)

For example you can use 'Per Class' approach for classes that are relatively small and follow [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). But if you have legacy code with a giant *Manager class it is fine to use 'Per Method' and have dedicated test case for only one of its methods. I think that choosing naming strategy for tests is at least as important as test code organization.

Using [code coverage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage) tool can help you find spots of untested code. It is less useful as metric. Having high code coverage does not necessarily mean that you have good tests. At the end of the day what matters is that you have [meaningful and readable tests.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503627)

Comment: Lol why does the xunit website use junit?

Answer (score 7):

If you're trying on TDD, then you shouldn't be writing any code at all without having a failing test that tells you to do so. By implication, then, you'll never have a class that doesn't have one or more tests for it. A rule of thumb that tends to get quoted is that you should end up with about 2.5 times as much test source as main source.

Comment: Just to add to that - testing things like getters and setters really isn't needed. So, not quite **everything** is needed (though getters and setters would be tested by other parts of your code).

Comment: @getn_outchea Does that also contribute to the code coverage?

Comment: Assuming your getters and setters are purely getters and setters, they should be used by other portions of your program, and thus they'll be inherently covered.

Comment: @Kal: I know I've heard it in a presentation given by [Neal Ford](http://www.nealford.com/). I don't recall if I've come across it in written form. If anywhere, I'd expect to find it somewhere on the [Pragmatic Bookshelf](http://pragprog.com/titles).

Comment: I think the idea with not explicitly testing getters/setters is best summed up by the Law of Diminishing Returns.  That is, the benefit of writing the tests is outweighed by the fact that the time spent writing them would have been better spent furthering other aspects of the project.  Strictly due to the fact that the test in all likelihood cannot fail.  Addition of bounds checking or any other logic would of course make for a different scenario.

Comment: While trivial methods like getters and setters may not need explicit tests, the creation of them should still be driven by tests, and any such method without test coverage should be removed or covered.

Comment: An auto implemented property is also an implementation detail. You shouldn't assume that get/set is auto-implemented. That may change later - and you may not have test coverage or have broken tests because of that assumption. At some point you will likely be setting that property from a constructor or something, and you would have test coverage there. That is the most common case, but you should be writing that test before the inception of the property and class that contains it.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't recommend a strict mapping of one test per class. Some classes may not have much worth testing on their own. Some classes may require multiple tests because you want to specify different setups for different cases. You should use a code coverage tool like Cobertura and try to cover as much code as possible. Also you should look at the code you're testing and see what kind of different data should break it, and try to test it with different combinations of sample data (so 100% code coverage is not the end of testing, of course).

Answer (score 2):

Though better than 1:1 ratio or over 100% coverage is ideal, in general I tend to abide by "test that which could possibly break".

This means only testing code with 'working parts'. This excludes POJOs, DTOs, thin wrapper/adapter classes and classes that only exist to fit a framework, and so on.

Also, "test only code that is under your control". This generally means not writing explicit tests for generated code—such as Web service clients generated from WSDL (but it still makes sense to cover them as part of tests written for your own classes).

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing TDD and extreme programming, (I think this helps explain it), you program in pairs.  The first person writes a test for a feature that doesn't yet exist.  The test should prove that the feature is 100% functional and handles all required cases.  The second programmer then writes the code that makes the test pass perfectly.  It must be rewritten until it completely satisfies the test.  Usually you maintain a test suite for TDD which can be rerun constantly, detecting any failures and generating a report - though this is ambitious for personal use.

In any case, for TDD a new feature cannot exist without a new test being made first - the test Drives the Development.  So, your test is there for every feature by default if you're doing it right.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not strict as other commenters about writing the test fist and code afterwards. You should do that, but not many people actually do that. The important thing is to write tests ideally before writing code, or right after you wrote the code. But not days/weeks/months/years after that, because you wouldn't do it and the test would suck.

I usually divide application to several parts: application logic, business logic, data access layer, domain objects and helper classes. It is most important to test completely business logic and helper classes. Other parts of application are less important, but you can test some parts. Also do some integration tests.

The most important thing is not to overthink it. Just try to do it on some small project and you will see by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This quote from Uncle Bob (author of Clean Code) may answer your question:

> The structure of your tests should not be a mirror of the structure of your code. The fact that you have a class named X should not automatically imply that you have a test class named XTest.

[Source](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2017/10/03/TestContravariance.html)

By coupling the tests to the code structure, the tests are more likely to change when the code changes, making the tests more fragile (e.g. during refactoring when classes are splitted or merged).